# Function parse_ini_file returning bool(false)

Tags: php

I have this php code (on index.php):

```
$props = array();
$props = parse_ini_file('property.ini');
var_dump($props);
```

And the var_dump print this:

bool(false)bool(false)bool(false)bool(false)bool(false)bool(false)

The 'property.ini' is in the same folder than index.php

What I'm doing wrong?? Help!!!

property.ini contains:

```
DB_NAME = "name"
DB_USER = "user"
DB_PASSWORD = "passwprd"
DB_HOST = "host"
TABLE_PREFIX = "mp_"
```

Comment: How does your config file looks like? (See the example of a ini file on the website which Fred -ii- posted)

Comment: Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: I read the manual, but I can't find any problem in my property.ini that could be the cause. This is what my ini file contains:    DB_NAME = "name"
DB_USER = "user"
DB_PASSWORD = "passwprd"
DB_HOST = "host"
TABLE_PREFIX = "mp_"

Comment: Put your config file in your question, and not in comments.

Comment: @Anita [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26935224/edit) with the contents of the ini file. We shouldn't have to read comments to find additional info on your question.

Comment: I don't have a config file :(

Comment: You're trying to run a DB file, that's not how it works. Tell us what you wish to accomplish. I think you want to include, not parse.

Comment: [Cannot replicate](http://i.imgur.com/aERwUrb.jpg)

Comment: I want to use the values that are in property.ini, read from that file, and in case some value change in the future, I only need to change it on the property.ini file, and don't have to look on the entire code for hardcode values. Thats the reason why I need to read that file :)

Comment: @Anita My answer should work for you and is pretty easy! Think my solution is easier to understand

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you want to include this file like this:

```
require_once("property.ini.php");
```

And you can set the values with define like this:

```
define('DB_NAME', "name");
define('DB_USER', "user");
define('DB_PASSWORD', "passwprd");
define('DB_HOST', "host");
define('TABLE_PREFIX', "mp_");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ini file should look like this

```
DB_NAME = "name"
DB_USER = "user"
DB_PASSWORD = "passwprd"
DB_HOST = "host"
TABLE_PREFIX = "mp_"
```

It should go in property.ini, in same folder as the php file.

Your php file is OK, but try this

```
<?php
if(!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/property.ini')){
    echo 'File '.__DIR__ . '/property.ini does not exist';
    die();
}
$props = parse_ini_file(__DIR__ . '/property.ini');
print_r($props);
```

Maybe the path is wrong